# Does Swift 2 work on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

When building with Xcode 7 beta using Swift 2, can iOS 8 devices be used as deployment targets?

I remember that swift runtime gets embedded as dynamic framework so each app uses its own version of swift instead of iOS's version of swift, but I can't be sure.

On a related note, as of July 12, can you submit app to app store containing Swift 2?

Comment: You can't be sure?  Yes you can.  Test it yourself.